# Change TextView text on button click in Android Studio ( Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I've recently started learning Kotlin and during the lessons, I study we've created an app in Android that does change an image when a button is pressed, the question is how I can create the same app but changing TextView's text when button is pressed?

Below is the code for the app that works with images.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var Images = intArrayOf(R.drawable.sophh, R.drawable.soph2, R.drawable.soph3)
    var index = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun ChangeImage(view: View) {
        var image_view = findViewById(R.id.image_view1) as ImageView

        image_view.setImageResource(Images[index])
        index++

        if (index == Images.size) {
            index = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just put `myTextView.setText("Some text...")` inside the callback of the button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var text = intArrayOf("One","Two,"Three")
text_view.text=text[index]

Answer (score 0):

**In kotlin**

```
textview.text= "My text"
```

In Java

```
textview.setText("My text");
```